# How to update object with an image field - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called `ProductImage` that contains a few fields and an Django `ImageField`. In this case I already have the object created, and I want to update the `featured` boolean in the object.

Problem is that when I do a `$http.put()` (Using AngularJS) I get an error returned saying:

> The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.

My REST API Object looks like this on the GET request:

```
{
    "id": 15,
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/products/photo_1_5.JPG",
    "alt": "HelloWorld",
    "featured": false,
    "product": 1
}
```

The HTTP PUT request I send looks like this: (Notice `featured` has been changed to `true`)

```
{
    "id": 15,
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/products/photo_1_5.JPG",
    "alt": "HelloWorld",
    "featured": true,
    "product": 1
}
```

So... How do I update my object without having to re-submit/re-upload the image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `PUT` to update an object you have to send a full instance. So in your case you have to send a image file for `image` not an url to the image.

The easiest solution is probably to use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`. Then you can do a partial update and send only the updated fields.

```
{
    "featured": true
}
```

Comment: When I do a `PATCH` and leave out the `image` out of the dictionary, it treats it as `image=None` and it overwrite the old `image` value with `null`. Is it some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Have you overridden the `update` methods of the serializer or view?